# How to get text from all text fields created inside for loop in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, uiview, uitextfield

I created Textfields like below

```
for (DataSourceForController *ds in _dataArray)
{

    NSString *name = ds.labelName;
    NSString *bits  = ds.textLabelPlceholder;


    _paramNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width*0, (self.frame.size.height*0.15)+i, self.frame.size.width*0.45,self.frame.size.height*0.05)];
    _paramNameLabel.text = name;
    _paramNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    _paramNameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    [self addSubview:_paramNameLabel];

    _paramValue =  [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width*0.45, (self.frame.size.height*0.15)+i, self.frame.size.width*0.55,self.frame.size.height*0.05)];
    _paramValue.placeholder = bits;
    _paramValue.textAlignment= NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    _paramValue.delegate = self;
    _paramValue.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:35/255.0 green:185/255.0 blue:235/255.0 alpha:1];
    [self addSubview:_paramValue];
    i=self.frame.size.height*.1+i;
}
```

How can i get the text from each textfield like _paramVlue.text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `UITextField` in `NSMutableArray`. Try below code:

```
 NSMutableArray *textFieldArr = [NSMutableArray alloc]]init;
 for (DataSourceForController *ds in _dataArray)
{

NSString *name = ds.labelName;
NSString *bits  = ds.textLabelPlceholder;


_paramNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width*0, (self.frame.size.height*0.15)+i, self.frame.size.width*0.45,self.frame.size.height*0.05)];
_paramNameLabel.text = name;
_paramNameLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
_paramNameLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self addSubview:_paramNameLabel];

_paramValue =  [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width*0.45, (self.frame.size.height*0.15)+i, self.frame.size.width*0.55,self.frame.size.height*0.05)];
_paramValue.placeholder = bits;
_paramValue.textAlignment= NSTextAlignmentCenter;
_paramValue.delegate = self;
_paramValue.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:35/255.0 green:185/255.0 blue:235/255.0 alpha:1];
[self addSubview:_paramValue];
[textFieldArr addObject:_paramValue];
i=self.frame.size.height*.1+i;
}
```

Now suppose yow want to get text of `UITextField` at index 2 then write below line:

```
 NSString *str = [(UITextField *)[textFieldArr objectAtIndex:2] text];
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I found another easy way

```
 for (UITextField *feild in [self subviews])
    {
        if ([feild isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]])
        {
             NSLog(@"Text = %@ ",feild.text);
        }
    }
```